# Get WindowsAccount for current user that made the request to the WCF service

Tags: .net, wcf, authentication

**Hi,**

I got a WCF service(session) that uses both WindowsAuthentication and regular UserName/Password authentication.

Now I need to get the current user on the client that have sent the request to the WCF service.

I know that this can be done in IAuthorizationPolicy but Im not sure how to do this in a webmethod?

I have tried this :

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
```

This does however only return the current user that runs the WCF service(it seems), not the client user that have med the current requst?

Pleas advice

**BestRegards**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

The identity of the user that sent the request is avaialable in WCF through the AuthorizationContext,

```
AuthorizationContext context =
ServiceSecurityContext.Current.AuthorizationContext;
```

That works for any kind of authentication method, no matter if you use windows or username/password.

WCF by default does not set the identity in the running thread so you shouldn't able to get it with WindowsIdentity.

Regards
Pablo.